# Facebook PHP SDK showing page events

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can i list events of a facebook page on my site?

Is it possible? And i wouldn't need getUser() etc. since I am not grabbing anything from the user?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ and this is only for a specific event id, which also should be from the user logged in that is visting the site.. thats not what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

use your user id in place of get user.

```
<?php
//Facebook
session_start();
require_once "php-sdk/src/facebook.php"; 

$config = array(
    "appId" => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    "secret" => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    "cookie" => true );
$fb = new Facebook($config);
$uid = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
$access_token = $fb->getAccessToken();
$permissions_list = $fb->api(
   '/me/permissions',
   'GET',
   array(
      'access_token' => $access_token )
      );
?>
```